# Should I refactor these nested each blocks?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I'm wondering if there's a way to refactor this method to minimize the levels of indentation. After reading clean code Uncle Bob says once a method gets past two levels it becomes harder to understand what's going on.. I don't think this method is overly complex, but I think it could be cleaned up and look more like a story.

here is my method

```
def sync!(xml_document, language_id, status_id, file)
  survey = sync_survey.(xml_document, status_id)
  sync_survey_label.(xml_document, survey.id, language_id, file)

  xml_document.xpath('//page').each do |xml_section|
    section = sync_section.(xml_section, survey.id)
    sync_section_label.(xml_section, section.id, language_id)

    xml_section.xpath('.//question_group').each do |xml_question_group|
      question_group = sync_question_group.(xml_question_group, section.id)
      sync_question_group_label.(xml_question_group, question_group.id, language_id)

      xml_question_group.xpath('.//question').each do |xml_question|
        question = sync_question.(xml_question, question_group.id)
        sync_question_label.(xml_question, question.id, language_id)

        xml_question.xpath('.//answerchoice').each do |xml_choice|
          choice = sync_choice.(xml_choice, question.id)
          sync_choice_label.(xml_choice, choice.id, language_id)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  survey
end
```

So, Im traversing an xml and saving to the corresponding methods. each survey has many sections which has many question_groups which has many questions which has many choices.

I know I could extract each loop into a method but then I would still have 4 levels of indentation.

I want to do something like...

```
def sync!(xml_document, language_id, status_id, file)
  survey = sync_survey.(xml_document, status_id)
  sync_survey_label.(xml_document, survey.id, language_id, file)
  sync_sections.(xml_document)
  sync_section_labels.(xml_document, language_id)
  sync_question_groups.(xml_document)
  sync_question_group_labels.(xml_document, language_id)
  sync_questions.(xml_document)
  sync_question_labels.(xml_document, language_id)
  sync_choices.(xml_document)
  sync_choice_labels.(xml_document, language_id)

  survey
end
```

Are there any ideas to do something like this or make this code more readable? Is it even necessary to refactor it? Any ideas are welcome.

Here is the full class

```
class SurveyBuilder
  attr_reader  :xml_parser, :sync_survey, :sync_survey_label, :sync_section, :sync_section_label, :sync_question, :sync_question_label, :sync_question_group, :sync_question_group_label, :sync_choice, :sync_choice_label

  def initialize
    @sync_survey = SurveyBuilder::Sync::Survey.new
    @sync_survey_label = SurveyBuilder::Sync::SurveyLabel.new
    @sync_section = SurveyBuilder::Sync::Section.new
    @sync_section_label = SurveyBuilder::Sync::SectionLabel.new
    @sync_question = SurveyBuilder::Sync::Question.new
    @sync_question_label = SurveyBuilder::Sync::QuestionLabel.new
    @sync_question_group = SurveyBuilder::Sync::QuestionGroup.new
    @sync_question_group_label = SurveyBuilder::Sync::QuestionGroupLabel.new
    @sync_choice = SurveyBuilder::Sync::Choice.new
    @sync_choice_label = SurveyBuilder::Sync::ChoiceLabel.new
    @xml_parser = SurveyBuilder::XMLParser.new
  end

  def call(file, status_id)
    xml_document = xml_parser.(file)
    language_id = Language.find_by(code: xml_document.xpath('//lang_code').children.first.to_s).id

    survey = sync!(xml_document, language_id, status_id, file)

    survey
  end

private
  def sync!(xml_document, language_id, status_id, file)
    survey = sync_survey.(xml_document, status_id)
    sync_survey_label.(xml_document, survey.id, language_id, file)

    xml_document.xpath('//page').each do |xml_section|
      section = sync_section.(xml_section, survey.id)
      sync_section_label.(xml_section, section.id, language_id)

      xml_section.xpath('.//question_group').each do |xml_question_group|
        question_group = sync_question_group.(xml_question_group, section.id)
        sync_question_group_label.(xml_question_group, question_group.id, language_id)

        xml_question_group.xpath('.//question').each do |xml_question|
          question = sync_question.(xml_question, question_group.id)
          sync_question_label.(xml_question, question.id, language_id)

          xml_question.xpath('.//answerchoice').each do |xml_choice|
            choice = sync_choice.(xml_choice, question.id)
            sync_choice_label.(xml_choice, choice.id, language_id)
          end
        end
      end
    end
    survey
  end

end
```

Comment: `sync_survey.(xml_document, status_id)` what is that syntax?

Comment: it's the shorthand for the call method. so sync_survey is an object that has a call method that finds_or_initializes a survey and saves it. It could be written as `sync_survey.call(xml_document, status_id` @EricDuminil

Comment: I think you might be better off refactoring that as `sync_survey.sync!(xml_document, status_id)` or something similar for clarity. It is also not very clear how you create those objects and how they fit in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first stab would be something like:

```
def sync!(xml_document, language_id, status_id, file)
  survey = sync_survey.(xml_document, status_id)
  sync_survey_label.(xml_document, survey.id, language_id, file)

  xml_document.xpath('//page').each do |xml_section|
    sync_section(xml_section, ...)
  end

  survey
end

def sync_section(xml_section, ...)
  ...
  xml_section.xpath('.//question_group').each do |xml_question_group|
    sync_question_group(xml_question_group, ...)
  end
end 

def sync_question_group(xml_question_group, ...)
  ...
  xml_question_group.xpath('.//question').each do |xml_question|
    sync_question(xml_question, ...)
  end
end

def sync_question(xml_question, ...)
  ... 
  xml_question.xpath('.//answerchoice').each do |xml_choice|
    sync_choice(xml_choice, ...)
  end
end

def sync_choice(xml_choice, ...)
  ...
end
```

I elided a fair bit since I am not sure how you defined the existing `sync_question_group` which is used in a confusing way with the dot-syntax.

Comment: This was my first thought too. The only thing I don't like is each method is doing more than one thing.. sync_section would be saving each section then calling sync_question_group which would call sync question... etc. Maybe what I'm trying to do isnt possible in the scenario. I edited my original question to show the full class @MarcRohloff

Comment: You could break it up further I guess. You had originally wanted something like: `sync_sections.(xml_document); ...;sync_question_groups(xml_document)`

But the problem I see with that is that each question group needs access to it's section. You would have to change that last bit to:

    `sync_question_groups.(xml_document, sync_sections)`